# Looking up a GuildMember by their tag or ID

Tags: discord.js

I am building a bot that integrates Google Sheets to Discord that assigns roles to users. I have everything working as far as the bot can read and parse the webhook message.

I'm able to effectively lookup the Role from the parsed messaged using

```
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === UserToUpgradeLevel);
```

However, I can't figure out how to look up the user to apply the role. Using the following **only** works if I look up the bot by ID. If I look up any other user by ID, I get *undefined*

```
// get the member
        const user = client.users.cache.find(user => user.displayName === UserToUpgrade).id
        
        const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(user);
        if (! member) return console.error("404: user with ID", UserToUpgrade, "not found in guild", guild.name);

        // get the role
        const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === UserToUpgradeLevel);
        if (! role) return console.error("404: role with ID", UserToUpgradeLevel, "not found in guild", guild.name);
        
        // add role to member
        member.roles.add(role);
```

So, my question is, why can't I look up any others users? If I try and return the user, it's undefined, which of course means that if I try and fire member.roles.add(role) against an undefined member, the bot crashes with the error of **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')**

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `client.users.cache.find()` when you can use `message.guild.members.cache.find()?`. You can't directly search a user using `clients.users`. You need to fetch the guild first and then fetch the user which is very complicated. You can simply use `message.guild.members.cache.find()` method as you are using `messageCreate` event.

Your code should look like this:

```js
// Fetch the user using message.guild method
const user = message.guild.members.cache.find(user => user.displayName === UserToUpgrade);

if (!user) return console.error("404: user with display name", UserToUpgrade, "not found in guild", message.guild.name);

const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === UserToUpgradeLevel);

if (!role) return console.error("404: role with the name", UserToUpgradeLevel, "not found in the guild", message.guild.name);

// You can directly add the role, no `id` is needed
user.roles.add(role)
  .then(() => console.log(`Added role ${role.name} to ${user.displayName}`))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error adding role:', error));
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code is much cleaner than mine, for sure.

I was able to get my code to work by wrapping it in a 2 second SetTimeout and then doing an await guild.members.fetch();

I also had to wrap your code in the same SetTimeout and use the guild.members.fetch or the bot continued to not see the other users.